# How to disable TListView column clicks?

Tags: listview, delphi, delphi-7, tlistview

Is there a way to disable column clicking on `TListView` ?

I know I can ignore the click, but I want the column to be un-clickable/disabled in some situations.
I have searched for a solution but can't seem to find one.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `TListView.ColumnClick` property to `False`